# How to disable a text-box when clicking on other radio-buttons using a single function in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the text-box (its id is `text1`), when clicking on other radio buttons using a single function. According to my code the text-box is showing when the user is clicking on the radio button (its id is `rd_other`). But when the user clicking on the other radio buttons, after clicking the above radio button (its id is `rd_other`) the text-box is not disabling.

Here is HTML my code.

```
<input type="radio" name="rd_other" id="rd_other" value="rd_other" data-toggle="radio" onchange="enableText()">Other (please specify)

<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1"class="form-control input-sm jfl" readonly="readonly" style="display: none;"/>

<input type="radio" name="rdn1" id="rdn1" value="rdn1" data-toggle="radio">I haven't received the disc

<input type="radio" name="rdn2" id="rdn2" value="rdn2" data-toggle="radio">I lost or damaged the protective cover
```

Here is my javaScript code.

```
function enableText() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
    text1.readOnly = false;
    text1.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: wait, where are the other radio buttons? I just see rd_other.

Comment: *"But when the user clicking on the other radio buttons, after clicking the above radio button (its id is rd_other) the text-box is not disabling."* Well...why would it? You haven't hooked up any event handler on the other ones.

Comment: You're noticeably not using jQuery, why is that tag there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to make sure there are no confusions, onchange will only fire when a radio button is selected.

Secondly, you would have to hook up an onchange function to the two other radio buttons. The function below should work.

```
function disableText() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
    text1.readOnly = true;
    text1.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
function disable() {
    //one radio button
    var radio = document.getElementById("your_radio_button_id");
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("your_checkbox_id");
    if (radio.checked == true) {
        checkbox.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

or like this

```
function disable() {

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("your_radio_button_group_name");
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("your_checkbox_id");
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked == true) {
            checkbox.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this like this:

```
window.enableText = function(e) {    
    var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
    if(e.id == "rd_other2") { 
        text1.readOnly = false;
        text1.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        text1.readOnly = true;
        text1.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

please check the full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reg027/7c95s5n2/) :)